# correct syntax for the hook user_receive_packet in ejabberd-18.12?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

Current code :

```
user_receive_packet({Packet, C2SState}) ->

    ?INFO_MSG("~p.", [Packet]),
    {Packet, C2SState}.
```

Getting error when the hook is invoked:

```
[error] Hook user_receive_packet crashed when running... 
** Reason = {error,function_clause...
```

I guess the function arguments are wrong. What should be the correct syntax ? I am using ejabberd-18.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Syntax:

```
user_receive_packet({Packet, #{jid := JID} = C2SState}) ->

    {Packet, C2SState}.
```